# How do I use the next-env.d.ts file in Next.js?

Tags: typescript, enums, next.js

I noticed a file called next-env.d.ts in my Next.js typescript project. I wanted to declare some enums that I can use throughout my Next.js files. How do I do this and then access these enums throughout my project?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

next-env.d.ts file is explained here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript

> A file named next-env.d.ts will be created in the root of your project. This file ensures Next.js types are picked up by the TypeScript compiler. You cannot remove it, however, you can edit it (but you don't need to).

For what your are trying to achieve with the enums, you can export your enum as a regular ES Module, so you can import it whenever you want in your code.

Hope that helps.

Comment: We shouldn't expect something like `/// <reference types="some_package_name"/>` to work if there's no `@types/some_package_name` module part of [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped), should we?

Answer (score 8):

As of Next 11, the recommendation for the `next-env.d.ts` file has been changed, as it is now regenerated on each build.

You should not edit it, but instead create a new file for your own types and add it to your `tsconfig.json` `include`.

But for enums you don't need any of that, just declare it in a regular `.ts` file and import them normally.

**Source** (to old doc, the following note has apparently been removed from the docs from v13.4.5): https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/v13.4.4/docs/basic-features/typescript.md#existing-projects :

> A file named next-env.d.ts will be created at the root of your project. This file ensures Next.js types are picked up by the TypeScript compiler. **You should not remove it or edit it** as it can change at any time. This file should not be committed and should be ignored by version control (e.g. inside your .gitignore file).

> Instead of editing next-env.d.ts, you can include additional types by adding a new file e.g. additional.d.ts and then referencing it **in the include array in your tsconfig.json**.

See also: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/26533

Comment: There is no mention of this file anymore in the Next.js docs, but still in v13.3 it is regenerated on build.