# Is there any documentation for this TypeScript syntax?

Tags: typescript, types

As per this other [thead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61420392/how-do-i-use-the-next-env-d-ts-file-in-next-js) on the topic, next.js automatically generates a [next-env.d.ts](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript) file, to ensure that the next.js types are picked up by the TypeScript compiler. The `next-env.d.ts` file looks like this:

```
/// <reference types="next" />
/// <reference types="next/types/global" />
```

Fine, but I couldn't find the TypeScript documentation for this - is there any, or is it an experimental feature? I'd like to manually create a similar file for another package that doesn't generate the types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. It's called "Triple-Slash Directives":

> Triple-slash directives are single-line comments containing a single XML tag. The contents of the comment are used as compiler directives.

Read more about this in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html).